# How to fix the error with split() in php?

Tags: php

How to fix this error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function split() in /home/kmusi/public_html/base.php(725) : eval()'d code:9 Stack trace: #0 /home/kmusi/public_html/base.php(725) : eval()'d code(74): gregorian_to_jalaliq2a('1519984652') #1 /home/kmusi/public_html/base.php(761): when_to_html_override_1_in_gregorian2jalali_overrides_php('1519984652', '7') #2 /home/kmusi/public_html/base.php(822): call('when_to_html...', Array) #3 /home/kmusi/public_html/app/format.php(780): call_override('when_to_html', Array) #4 /home/kmusi/public_html/app/format.php(581): when_to_html('1519984652', '7') #5 /home/kmusi/public_html/app/format.php(826): post_html_fields(Array, 1, NULL, Array, NULL, Array) #6 /home/kmusi/public_html/app/format.php(986): other_to_q_html_fields(Array, 1, NULL, Array, NULL, Array) #7 /home/kmusi/public_html/app/list.p in /home/kmusi/public_html/base.php(725) : eval()'d code on line 9

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: @Igor Carvalho i use php 7

Comment: Did you not search for the error on the Internet? I found one and used it to mark it as a duplicate. I had forgotten I answered for it also, *heh*. It also contains a few comments you should see.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `split()` function was removed in PHP 7. You can replace it with [preg_split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) or [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 9):

Replace `split()` with `explode()`

```
$string = "a, b, c";
$array = explode(", ", $string);
```

It will give you array with 3 values in it.

`split` was deprecated in previous version of php but I think in php 7 it is removed so this is why it is saying undefined.